# Does melatonin need to be kosher?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, food, medicine

I'm not certain if it's medication or not. I'm speaking of plain, non-flavored powder capsules.

Comment: What's the definition of "a medication"? Why does that matter here?

Comment: @DoubleAA It might matter, on certain [conditions](https://www.kosharot.co.il/%D7%9B%D7%A9%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%AA%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A4%D7%95%D7%AA)

Comment: @DoubleAA As per a conversation that I had a couple of months ago with a rabbi from the Star-K (I don't remember who), there are more leniencies to be had when it comes to medications vs. supplements. If melatonin is a medication, it is subject to those leniencies. If it is a supplement, it is not.